# 100% width footer in 960 grid

Tags: css, grid, 960.gs

I have a footer and am wanting it to be 100% in width using the 960 grid system, all is fine I can it to work within a div tag using an id. but the grid floats all the way to the left of the page while the whole site using the grid is centered on the page. I have tried prefix_2 to give a push over to the right but it doesn't line up correctly.
Here is my code to start with.

```
<div id="footer" class="container_12"><img class="prefix_6" id="abs" align="right"     src="#img" width="500" height="258" />
<br /><br />
<div class="grid_2"><p><a href="#link">Home</a></p><p><a href="#link">Services</a></p><p><a href="#link">Plans</a></p></div>
<div class="grid_2"><p><a href="#link">Pricing</a></p><p><a href="#link">Design</a></p><p><a href="#link">Logos</a></p></div>
<div class="grid_2 suffix_6"><p>Call Tool Free:</p><p>1-800-495-5933</p><p><a href="#link">Contact Us</a></p></div>
<div class="grid_6"><a href="#link"><img src="#img" width="16" height="16" />Follow me on Twitter</a> <img src="#img" width="16" height="16" />Become a Fan on Facebook</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #f0e9d8;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6e2500;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 250px;
}
#abs {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(auto,auto,500px,auto);
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: 960 Grid System. Got it fixed thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want that footer would be 100% width? That's a easy fix. 
You just need an another wrapper around your footer code. I would do it like this:

```
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container_12">
            <img class="prefix_6" id="abs" align="right"     src="#img" width="500" height="258" />
            <br /><br />
            <div class="grid_2"><p><a href="#link">Home</a></p><p><a href="#link">Services</a></p><p><a href="#link">Plans</a></p></div>
            <div class="grid_2"><p><a href="#link">Pricing</a></p><p><a href="#link">Design</a></p><p><a href="#link">Logos</a></p></div>
            <div class="grid_2 suffix_6"><p>Call Tool Free:</p><p>1-800-495-5933</p><p><a href="#link">Contact Us</a></p></div>
            <div class="grid_6"><a href="#link"><img src="#img" width="16" height="16" />Follow me on Twitter</a> <img src="#img" width="16" height="16" />Become a Fan on Facebook</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css for that would be:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #f0e9d8;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6e2500;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#abs {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(auto,auto,500px,auto);
}
```

Comment: when I set the width to 100% the footer leans all the way to the left, I'd like to stay centered like the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the footer's width to be 100% just remove it from the 960 Grid System.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      Header
    </header>
    <section class="container_12">
      <!--960 grid-->
    </section>
    <footer class="footer-main">
      <!--img-->
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.footer-main {
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Within the container_12 it doesn't come out correctly, it stays inside that container. I need it to take up 100% in width of that page.